# weighted logistic regression in R - beginner level

Tags: r, logistic-regression, glm

I am trying to do a logistic regression in R with weights, but I dont really know how it works. When I apply weights, something weird happens and all the values appear at 1 but I dont see why? (also how can I fit a line through the points?)
I try to calculate a correlation coefficient for the observed value to the predicted value. Also I am aiming for a plot with "fra" on the y-axis ranging from 0-1, the temp on the x-axis, the fra values in the plot and a line for the regression (something like this example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7WLyA.jpg)
Thanks!

What I have so far (made up code):

```
#Dataframe
temp=c(1,1,2,2,3,4,4,5,5,6,6,7,7,8,8)
fra=c(0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.5,0.2,0.2,0.3,0.1,0.3,0.4,0.0,0.5)
bin=c(0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1)
test1 <- as.data.frame(cbind(temp,bin,fra))

#Overview                       
plot(test1$temp, test1$bin)
plot(test1$fra)
boxplot(test1$temp ~ test1$bin, horizontal=TRUE)
#Logistic Regression without weight
glmt1 <- glm(test1$bin~test1$temp, family=binomial)
coefficients(summary(glmt1)) 
fit1 <- fitted(glmt1)
#plot
plot(test1$temp, fit1, ylim=range(0,1))
#line should go to points..???
lines(test1$bin, glmt1$fitted, type="l", col="red")

#with weighted
glmt2 <- glm(test1$bin~test1$temp, family=binomial, weights=test1$fra)
coefficients(summary(glmt2)) 
fit2 <- fitted(glmt2)
plot(test1$temp, fit2, ylim=range(0,1))
```

Comment: This question should maybe be asked in Cross Validated (stats.stackexchange.com) since it concerns estimation techniques.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be asked on [stats.SE], since it concerns estimation techniques.

Answer (score 1):

You are only giving a positive weight to cases where `bin == 1`. That removes all variation in the response variable (you have `fit1$bin` in the LHS this time). That means your model always predicts 1 no matter what the value of `temp1$temp`